# Анимация открытия CommandBar

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp

Нужна помощь с CommandBar.

Создал две анимации: одна при открытии CommandBar, другая при закрытии. Суть анимации:

- при открытии свойство BackgroundOpacity с помощью DoubleAnimation
  меняется с 1 до 0.3.
- при закрытии свойство возвращается в состояние 1.

Xaml код (писал также в C#, но тоже самое):

```
<UserControl.Resources>
        <Storyboard x:Name="opacityOpenChangeStoryboard">
            <DoubleAnimation From="1" To="0.3" Duration="0:0:1"
                             Storyboard.TargetName="CommandBar"  Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background.Opacity"/>
        </Storyboard>
        <Storyboard x:Name="opacityCloseChangeStoryboard">
            <DoubleAnimation From="0.3" To="1" Duration="0:0:1"
                             Storyboard.TargetName="CommandBar" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background.Opacity"/>
        </Storyboard>
    </UserControl.Resources>
```

При открытии вызывается событие Openning, при закрытии Closing. 
Проблема в том, что анимация при открытии не воспроизводится, но при закрытии все работает хорошо. С помощью отладчика проверял вызывается ли код - да, код вызывается, но не пашет анимация открытия.

Описал все как мог, надеюсь на помощь.

Comment: Ресурсы — это хорошо, а как именно вы триггерите вашу анимацию?

Comment: В событии Opening вызывается метод opacityOpenChangeStoryboard.Begin()

Answer (score 1):

Разобрался, необходимо было использовать не DoubleAnimation и свойство Opacity, а ColorAnimation и изменять цвет Background.

Вот код:

```
<Storyboard x:Name="fadeOn">
    <ColorAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="CommandBar"
                    Storyboard.TargetProperty="(CommandBar.Background).(SolidColorBrush.Color)"
                    To="#7F2D2D30"
                    Duration="0:0:1"/>
</Storyboard>
<Storyboard x:Name="fadeOff">
    <ColorAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="CommandBar"
                    Storyboard.TargetProperty="(CommandBar.Background).(SolidColorBrush.Color)"
                    To="#FF2D2D30"
                    Duration="0:0:1"/>
</Storyboard>
```

Как и писал выше в событии используется fadeOn.Begin() и fadeOff.Begin()

```
private void CommandBar_Opening(object sender, object e)
{
    fadeOn.Begin();
}

private void CommandBar_Closing(object sender, object e)
{
    fadeOff.Begin()
}
```

Comment: Хм. То, что анимация цвета работает, это хорошо. А почему анимация Opacity не работала?

Comment: К сожалению  я сам так и не понял. Когда CommandBar закрывался, то появлялась анимация opacityCloseChangeStoryboard, т.е свойство Opacity становилось в 0.3 затем переходило в 1, но свойство Opacity не менялось тогда, когда CommandBar был открытым.